# Substitution error when calling bash code from inside script

Tags: bash, unix

I have a simple segment of code that works when I run it on it's own, although it doesn't work when it is called from a file.

Code below:

```
for files in *; do echo ${files::10}; done
```

When I try to put this inside a file (e.g. MyScript.sh) I run the following:

```
sh MyScript.sh
```

I receive the following error "MyScript.sh: 2: MyScript.sh: Bad substitution"

Why is this happening? How can this be fixed?

Comment: Are you sure that `sh` is `bash`?

Comment: `sh` is the POSIX shell, which does not support this form of substitution, use `bash`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725296/difference-between-sh-and-bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call it using `bash` not `sh` as you are using bash syntax

```
bash MyScript.sh
```

or add a shebang (as the first line in your script)

```
#! /bin/bash
```

and set execution permission

```
chmod +x MyScript.sh
```

then you can invoke it

```
./MyScript.sh
```